# Embedding between normal space and $[0,1]^{J}$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X,\tau)$ a Normal topological space, $\beta \subseteq \tau$ a
> basis  of $\tau$. Then, there exists a embedding between $X$ and $[0,1]^J$, with $J \subseteq \beta \times \beta$.

My attempt was:

> For any $\mathcal{F} \subseteq C(X,[0,1])$ a subset of the family of continuous functions  from $(X,\tau)$ to $([0,1], \sigma)$ with $\sigma$ the usual topology, the function
>
> $F:(X,\tau)$ $\rightarrow$ $([0,1]^{\mathcal{F}},\tau_{P})$ , $F(x)=\big( f(x) \big)_{f \in \mathcal{F}}$, with $\tau_P$ = the product topology
>
> $X$ normal implies Tychonoff; $X$ and $Y$ are $T_1$ (points are closed)
>
> Then F is a embedding.
>
> maybe exists $G: [0,1]^J \rightarrow [0,1]^{\mathcal{F}}$ surjective and countinuous?
> then $F \circ G$

Only hints please, not all the question, thankyou <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using normality or the special form of the index set that was hinted at, so your attempt is not correct for meta-reasons alone.

Try to use Urysohn functions for all pairs $(B, B')$ from the base with $\overline{B} \subseteq B'$ (for appropriate closed sets).

Do you know any theorems to recognise embeddings into a cube $[0,1]^J$? There is a quite famous one, also used to prove facts on Tychonoff spaces..